# Why does $route have to be included when unit testing $location only?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I wanted to write a unit test to confirm my "otherwise" logic was working correctly.  This is how I expected to do it:

```
it('should handle unknown routes properly', inject(function($location, $rootScope) {
    $location.path('/unknown');

    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect($location.path()).toBe('/yikes');
}));
```

However, what I discovered is that I had to inject $route to make this test work.  Keep in mind, the unit test code didn't have to use $route but apparently it needed to be instantiated to make $location work properly.

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpEcH9?p=preview) if you're interested in more details.  Why does $route have to be included when unit testing $location only?

I see lots of discussion that seems to be related:

- [issue 1213](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1213)
- [relevant commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/308598795af75c33a966ecb3124f4a640d72458d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your test doesn't work is because `$route` performs the redirect logic, and `$route` isn't instantiated directly or indirectly from your setup.  `$route` is instantiated only if it's injected as a dependency somewhere, such as the `ng-view` directive.  In a real Angular setup, you'll typically configure `$routeProvider` and define `ng-view` somewhere on the page.  If no `ng-view` exists, `$route` really shouldn't be instantiated and perform extra logic that slows down the app.  `$route` and `ng-view` are meant to be used together.

In order to get this working, you have to either

1. Inject `$route` somewhere or
2. Do a `$compile` on an element with `ng-view`.  It's important
   that `$route` be instantiated before the bad location is attempted
   or else `$route` won't know to redirect to the `otherwise` location.